# Set up MacTex distribution as default on mac os

Tags: mactex, mac, vim

I have installed the MacTex distribution on OSX10 and until now I've been using the TexShop editor quite successfully. I want to change and start writing latex using the Vim editor but I haven't nearly enough latex packages installed on the mac. 
Instead of having to download each package seperately using macports, **how do I set up vim to use the full latex distribution of MacTex** ?

Comment: It should "just work". MacTeX adds `/usr/texbin` to your path, which contains all the usual executables (and is what TeXshop actually runs). Those executables should know where the MacTeX packages are, and anything you wrote in TeXshop should work with vim. Where are you having problems?

Comment: Have you tried compiling your document with `pdflatex your_doc` from Terminal? If your MacTeX has any problems, eg. configuration of paths, it should fail.

Comment: How have you configured vim to call latex? Perhaps you have the wrong version of latex appearing first in your path or vim is calling the wrong version of latex explicitly. For the former change you shell settings and for the latter look in `.vimrc` or `.vim/plugin` or `.vim/ftplugin` and change what vim is doing. If you just delete any "extra" versions of latex that you have (it sounds like you have at least 2 installed?), then this will probably solve your problem too. The problem may also be that `TEXINPUTS` is not correctly defined...hard to say without more information.